# How can i convert any formula that is in a string form into real formula and implement into dynamically created form using Angular6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a `HomeComponent` in which i have a `JSON` which i am passing to another component called `CalculatorComponent` in which dynamic form is generating based on `JSON`. Basically dynamic calculators are generating from json which i am passing into `CalculatorComponent`. So i also have a formula inside the same `JSON` in a string form which is the value of a key in object.
But i am stuck on how to convert formula in a string form into form to get result in the resuld field of dynamic generated calculator.

Inside my `CalculatorComponent` i am generating dynamic calculator form and binding input fields variables dynamically and also getting the form fields values on form submit. But i also have formula inside my json in a string form and want to implement that formula on my form fields to get result in `Result` input field.

I have `JSON` inside 'home.component.ts' like this

```
this.dynamicFormJson = {
  heading : 'Percentage Calculator',
  totalFields : 3,
  inputs : [
    {label : 'Percent', placeholder : 'Enter Percentage Here', type : 'number', variable : 'percent'},
    {label : 'Amount', placeholder : 'Enter Amount Here', type : 'number', variable : 'amount'},
    {label : 'Result', placeholder : '', type : 'number', variable : 'res'}
  ],
  formula : "(percent * amount) / 100"
 }
```

I have this code in my `calculator.component.html`

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <form style="margin:100px 0 0 100px;background-color: lightgrey; padding: 
   20px;">
  <h2>{{formJson.heading}}</h2>
  <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let inputRow of formJson.inputs">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">{{inputRow.label}}</label>
    <input type="{{inputRow.type}}" class="form-control" 
     (change)="updateResult()"   
   [(ngModel)]="formInputsVar[inputRow.variable]" [ngModelOptions]=" 
  {standalone: true}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder=" 
  {{inputRow.placeholder}}">
  </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
   (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And in `calculator.component.ts` i have this code

```
    import { Component, OnInit , Input} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
     selector: 'app-calculator',
     templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
      })
    export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() formJson : any;
    formInputsVar = {};
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
     this.formJson.inputs.map((item : any)=>{
      if (!this.formInputsVar[item.variable]) {
      this.formInputsVar[item.variable] = '';
        }
       })
      }
    onSubmit(){
      console.log(this.formInputsVar);
     }

    }
```

Here is full working code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wf9vx)

I want to convert the formula that is in my `JSON` on my form fields so that i can get result in my `Result` field real time like angular 2 way binding. Here is the reference working [example](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/percentage) which i want to replicate

**Note**
I will have different calculators and each calculator's `JSON` will be different with different number of fields and different `formula`. Each calculator's json will be saved in my db but just for the sake of asking question i put all json in ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a input event, you define the function in your dynamicFormJson and then you call it in your calculator

```
 <input type="{{inputRow.type}}" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="formInputsVar[inputRow.variable]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" (input)="changeResult()" placeholder="{{inputRow.placeholder}}">
```

ts app.component:

```
this.dynamicFormJson = {
  heading : 'Percentage Calculator',
  totalFields : 3,
  inputs : [
    {label : 'Percent', placeholder : 'Enter Percentage Here', type : 'number', variable : 'percent'},
    {label : 'Amount', placeholder : 'Enter Amount Here', type : 'number', variable : 'amount'},
    {label : 'Result', placeholder : '', type : 'number', variable : 'res'}
  ],
  function:function(input) {
    input.res = input.amount * input.percent / 100;
    return input;
  }
}
```

ts calculator:

```
changeResult() {
    this.formInputsVar = this.formJson.function(this.formInputsVar);
  }
```

demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qmx8r

Comment: I will have different json , different fields and different formula for each calculator so how can i hardcode the function's definition specifying variable's name? variable names will be different for each calculators input fields

Comment: try different calculators on this [site](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/percentage)

You will see on this site that every calculator have different fields and have different formula.

Comment: you will need a function for each calculator

Comment: so where will be that function? in db inside json? because i have a single calculator component which i am using and passing json into it.

Comment: please give me an exmaple and edit my stackblitz. I am stuck on this issue.

Comment: glad to have helped :)